# How can I use the visual studio concurrency visualizer on metro projects?

Tags: .net, concurrency, profiling, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I want to use the concurrency visualizer, in visual studio 2012, to find concurrency bottlenecks during the startup of a WinRT metro ui project.

I think the main issue is I don't know the proper command to launch the program. The concurrency visualizer doesn't support launching winrt projects yet, so I have to specify the parameters (program, arguments, working directory) manually.

Currently I'm trying (with the %paths% unpacked):

- Program=%BuildDir%\AppX\%ProjectName%.exe
- Arguments=-ServerName:App.AppX2tv...%taken-from-start-screen-shortcut%-...jgr74.mca
- Working Directory=%BuildDir%\AppX\

Note that the concurrency visualizer *does* work when being attached the already-running process, I've tried it, I just can't seem to launch it (which is important for catching the startup phase).